# Liquidsoap: How to iterate over list of strings

Tags: liquidsoap

I would like to add a function to the `on_connect` parameter of [`input.harbor`](https://www.liquidsoap.info/doc-1.4.3/reference.html#input.harbor). The function gets the headers as a list of strings.
Now, I want to iterate over the list to log each header line (for debugging purposes).

How can I achieve this? I have already found [`list.iter`](https://www.liquidsoap.info/doc-1.4.3/reference.html#list.iter), but not sure how to apply it.

An example would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

After some try and error and further research I found the solution.

`list.iter` is indeed the way to go. Iterating over a list of strings (`[string, string, ...]`) would look like this:

```
myList = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]
list.iter(fun(item) -> print(item), myList)

# The output will look this way:
# aa
# bb
# cc
```

If you have a list of string pairs (`[(string, string), (string, string), ...]`) you have to do it slightly different:

```
myList = [("a", "aaa"), ("b", "bbb"), ("c", "ccc")]
list.iter(
  fun(item) -> print(
    fst(item) ^ " => " ^ snd(item)
  ),
  myList
)

# This will results in:
# a => aaa
# b => bbb
# c => ccc
```